# Grep match a word but not another word

Tags: regex, grep

I want to match a line with foo not followed by bar, e.g.

```
foo 123 <-- match
foo bar <-- not match
```

Using the following regex does not work:

```
echo "foo 123" | grep -E 'foo.*(?!bar).*'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

On systems that don't have `grep -P` like OSX you can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F 'foo' 'NF>1{s=$0; $1=""; if (!index($0,"bar")) print s}' file
```

**[Script Demo](http://ideone.com/dIYJJZ)**

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below grep command which uses `-P`(perl-regexp) parameter,

```
grep -P 'foo(?:(?!bar).)*$' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo 123
foo bar
$ grep -P 'foo(?:(?!bar).)*$' file
foo 123
```

Or

use only negative lookahead to check whether the string `bar` is after to `foo` without matching any following character.

```
$ grep -P 'foo(?!.*bar)' file
foo 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-v` to invert the match:

```
grep -v 'foo.*bar' file
```

Comment: But won't this match on lines without `foo` at all? However, `grep foo | grep -v bar` might work depending on the OP's requirements.